# self-adjoint operators and linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, differential-operators

Let $L$ be a self-adjoint differential operator given by $L=\frac{d}{dx}\left(a_2\frac{d}{dx}\right)+a_0$. If $u_1$ and $u_2$ are two solutions of $Lu=0$ and $J(u_1,u_2)=0$ for some $x$ for which $a_2(x)\not=0$, then show that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are linearly dependent.

I'm still learning about differential operators, but my knowledge of linear algebra is shaky. Linear dependence is $\exists c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $u_1=cu_2$.

Any help on any of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $u_1$ and $u_2$ are linearly dependent means that $\exists c\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $u_1 \equiv c u_2$. And $u_1$ and $u_2$ are linearly independent means that $c_1 u_1 + c_2 u_2 \equiv 0 $ iff $c_1=c_2=0$

Comment: @echzhen Ah, thank you.

Comment: Linear dependence of two vectors means that they are proportional. Linear independence means that the two vectors are not proportional, namely two vectors are said to be linearly independent if and only if the coefficients of every linear combination of these two vectors are all zero.

Comment: @Salvatore So, how does that tie into $u_1$ and $u_2$ being solutions of $Lu=0$?

Comment: You could take an arbitrary linear combination of u1 and u2 and plug it in the differential equation Lu=0, you should see if the coefficients of the linear combination are all zero

Comment: @Salvatore "namely two vectors are said to be linearly independent if and only if the coefficients of every linear combination of these two vectors are all zero" Sorry, but don't you think that  it's meaningless?

Comment: No, because that answered to a part of the question before it was edited